# How to handle "The notification platform is unavaible", System Exception

Tags: c#, exception, windows-10, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I'm working on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015 Rc. I developed a Universal App that sends toast notifications. I noticed that when deploying the App on RaspberryP2, I receive this exception:

> WinRT information: The notification platform is unavailable.

It's ok, I don't really need to show notifications on the IOT device, I just to make it run without throwing.

The code that throws:

```
  XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText02);
  XmlNodeList stringElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
  stringElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Title"));
  stringElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Text"));
  ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
  ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```

How can I avoid to run this code if the App is running on Windows 10 IoT? 
(I was looking about something like `if (NotificationsAvaibible) { } else { }`

Comment: It is marked as part of the Universal API Contract so it should have a non-throwing implementation on IoT. I'll follow up.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT This problem still exists with VS 2015 RTM and Windows IoT core 10.0.10556.

Comment: Yes, a VS update won't fix anything. You need a fixed IoT build. Not sure when that will be, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page shows the unavailable APIs at this time: 
https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/UnavailableApis.htm

If this doesn't work for your scenario:

```
if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.ToastNotificationActionTrigger"))
  {
     //put your line here which otherwise has an exception
  }
```

then you may need to resort to try...except for the line.